# How to get and convert MMALSharp image to OpenCV Mat image?

Tags: opencv, .net-core, raspberry-pi

I want To create face detection app for Raspberry pi3b (raspbian) by .net core 2.2.

I found a few libraries for that:

[MMALSharp](https://github.com/techyian/MMALSharp), 
[opencvsharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp)

But I did not found any methods that returns byte array or something similar that can contain image data in MMALSharp library. Is there any method in MMALSharp for get raw image from camera module to variable without writing image to disk?

I already have working code (on my windows laptop) that use Opencv (OpenCvSharp) which use laptop webcamera. But I need to use raspberry pi camera module.

I found only that method [Source](https://github.com/techyian/MMALSharp/blob/eb74148c76a21609af5bb13b02fb5867b5ce4ced/src/MMALSharp/MMALCamera.cs#L124)

```
TakeRawPicture(ICaptureHandler handler)
```

But it doesnt returns variable so I should to define my own function inside MMALSharp library and convert it OpenCV image variable.

Is there any better solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

MMALSharp has a `InMemoryCaptureHandler` class which essentially wraps a `List<byte>`. Create an instance of `InMemoryCaptureHandler` and pass it to the `TakeRawPicture` method. Once processing is complete, you can access the `WorkingData` property of your `InMemoryCaptureHandler` instance to access the image data.